# wxpython -- a frame or panel similar to labelframe in ttk?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, ttk

I used ttk's labelframes for many different things and have recently switched over to wxpython.  I can't, for the life of me, find a similar panel or frame in wxpython.  Does anyone know of any?  I'd prefer it be native but if it isn't there, it isn't there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like that? [wxPython `StaticBox`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/StaticBox.html#appearance-control-appearance)? Will act together with `STaticBoxSizer` as container for other controls.

Comment: You know, I passed right over looking at those as I assumed static box was just a box.  Thanks.